# How to rewrite nginx base file name?

Tags: nginx

How to rewrite nginx base file name?

http://pic.test.com/view.php?filename=947284035_234601603334998.jpg

to

http://pic.test.com/947284035_234601603334998

base file name

Answer (score 1):

the following should do it:

```
location /view.php {
  if ( $arg_filename ~ (.*)\.jpg ) {set $basename $1;}
  rewrite ^ $scheme://$host/$basename last;
}
```

Comment: hello, it say 404 Not Found
nginx/1.2.4

Comment: do you have a location set up to handle the rewritten request?

Comment: made a boneass mistake earlier (rewrite regex matches only the filename not the $args, so you need to do that in an if), updated my answer to work